# trying to connect asp.net and mysql trying to figure out mysql.data.dll

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net

I am trying to connect my asp.net project to mysql and I downloaded the mysql installer. When I try to add the reference the information is blank. Where do I find it? Thank you for any help. I also selected browse => and went the installer and looked in the bin folder and didn't find mysqldata.dll

[image]

Comment: How did you create this project, what project type did you choose?

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.Config` file:

Paste the `connectionStrings`

```
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="thisIsYourConnectionName" connectionString="uid=user1;pwd=YourPassword;server=localhost;database=yourdatabaseName;CharSet=utf8;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Import `System.Configuration` DLL to your `Page or Form` so with `MYSQL Data` DLL

Sample Testing the connection in your Page or form:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["thisIsYourConnectionName"].ConnectionString;  
            string queryString = "SELECT id,col1,col2,col3 FROM yourTableName;";  
            using (var connection = new MySqlConnection (connectionString))  
            {  
                var command = new MySqlCommand(queryString, connection);  
                connection.Open();  
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())  
                {  
                    while (reader.Read())  
                    {  
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", reader[0], reader[1]));  
                    }  
                }  
            }
```

Make sure you have created already your `Database` and `Tables` so with your `Username and Password` to your DB.

You can find mysql.data.dll here `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer` or something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.6.5\Assemblies\v4.0`

Comment: Hello, I do not have a web.config however I found this is in my appsettings.json "ConnectionStrings" that is where I replace it? Sorry very new to this

Comment: You are using a tag `asp.net` that's why i am assuming that `web.config` file exists.

Comment: I have the installer I downloaded it. but when I go into the bin folder I don't see mysql.data.dll

Comment: If your problem is only the `mysql.data.dll file` Add reference mysql.data.dll into your project then right click project name click `clean and build` => look to bin folder

Comment: Yes, I am using .net however in my project there is appsettings.json and not web.config I really appreciate your help

Comment: @Tasha Why did you accept this answer if it did not solve your problem?

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this I thought that check is because I found it helpful. I don't have web.config because I am creating a web application with appsettings.json. I did look inside mysql the downloaded files and I did not find mysql.data.dll

Comment: @VijunavVastivch Hello, I added mySQL.Data.DLL as a reference. I found my connection string in the appsettings.json. I entered in the connection string like you had and the code in a page and the output was all code. I changed the connection name and I referenced my own table name. Any help would be appreciated thank you